# c++ variable initialization in a class to send it using mpi

Tags: c++, mpi

I got stuck in a programming task. I want the elements of my stl vector to be placed in a

contiguous memory to send it with MPI_Send() routine.

here is an example:

```
class Tem
{

//...
private: 
 vector<double> lenghtVector (4500);//this gives a compilation error but I need to have a fixed sized vector

};
```

how can I have a vector with a serial memory of should I do something else?

Thanks.
Kindest Regards.

SRec

Comment: nevermind (question was changed while answering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of a vector are stored contiguously according to C++ Standard (23.2.4/1). To resize it you could use appropriate constructor in the initializer list of `Tem` class.:

```
class Tem
{
  Tem() : lenghtVector(4500) {};
private: 
 vector<double> lenghtVector;
};
```

Comment: Well thank you Krill,
Can I state the following ? Providing I do not exceed the initial length of the vector I can guarantee that the elements are held in contiguous. 
is it true?

Regards

Comment: Elements of a vector are stored contiguously all the time. Using `resize` or any other functions of `std::vector` will not change this rule.

Answer (score 1):

vector will do what you want, as the data is guaranteed to be contiguous.  Use &(v[0]) to get a pointer that you can pass to MPI_Send().

If you don't need the dynamic sizing of vector, you might want to look at the [Boost Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/array.html) class.  The size is fixed at compile time, but it is an STL compatible container, so you get begin(), end(), size(), etc.